Normality of the Lebesgue integral with respect to a Haar measure
Let $G$ be a locally compact second countable topological group and let $\mu$ be a Haar measure on $G$. I want to show that the weight $\varphi : {L^\infty(G)}^+ \to \overline{\mathbb R_+}$, $f \mapsto \int_G f \mathrm{d}\mu$ is normal i.e. $\sup_\alpha \varphi(f_\alpha) = \varphi(\sup_\alpha f_\alpha)$ for any bounded increasing net in $L^\infty(G)^+$. Here is my proof :
Let $(f_\alpha)$ be an increasing bounded net in $L^\infty(G)^+$, write $f = \sup_\alpha f_\alpha$. We know that $(f_\alpha)$ converges $\sigma$-weakly to $f$. As the usual locally convex topologies are metrizable on bounded set, there exists a subnet $(f_n)$ with indices in $\mathbb N$ converging $\sigma$-weakly to $f$ (simply use the convergence of the net for neighborhoods $B(f,\frac{1}{n+1}$). Let $(K_n)$ be an increasing sequence of compact subsets of $G$ such that $G = \bigcup_n K_n$ (locally compact $+$ second countable $\implies$ $\sigma$-compact). As $(f_n)$ converges $\sigma$-weakly, we have for all $m \in \mathbb N$, $\lim_\alpha \varphi(f_\alpha) = \lim_n \varphi(f_n) = \lim_n \int_G f_n \mathrm{d}\mu \geq \lim_n \int_G f_n \chi_{K_m} \mathrm{d}\mu = \int_G f \chi_{K_m} \mathrm{d}\mu$. By letting $m \to +\infty$, we get $\lim_\alpha \varphi(f_\alpha) \geq \int_G f \mathrm{d}\mu = \varphi(f)$ from monotone convergence theorem. As $f \geq f_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$, the reverse inequality is also true hence $\lim_\alpha \varphi(f_\alpha) = \varphi(f)$.
I'm pretty sure that should work but I lack experience with these notions. One thing that scares me is that I thought normality was supposed to replace monotone convergence theorem but it is not obvious in my proof how normality is somewhat equivalent to monotone convergence theorem (I know I'm using it but I don't feel like it's the main argument here).

It's interesting to know that there is an uncountable version of the monotone convergence theorem which doesn't require any sort of $\sigma$-finiteness of the measure. However, it is a result about equivalence classes of measurable functions modulo equality almost everywhere and not functions themselves. Normality for weights and traces is supposed to replace that uncountable version, and not the usual countable version about functions.

Thanks for your message, do you have any reference regarding this theorem ?

Sure: I learned it from Bourbaki's Integration, chap. IV, § 3, no. 6, prop. 14 (what you are interested in is the case $p=1$). I don't know of any other reference as most texts about classical integration do not even bother with distinguishing the function spaces $\mathscr L^p$ from their quotients $L^p$.
